# Plotting animation on basemap

Tags: python, for-loop, animation, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to animate a plot that moves across my map (field of regard of an airplane). I need it to iterate through my coordinates, so I tried using a for loop. When I run this, I get two frames, the first is empty, and the second is just an empty map.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

#map of Puerto Rico
map=Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=17.5,urcrnrlat=19.,llcrnrlon=-67.5, urcrnrlon=-65, epsg=4139)
map.arcgisimage(service='World_Shaded_Relief', xpixels = 2000)
plt.title("Flight Path of sbet 0059")

#sample coordinates
lon=[-63,-64,-65,-66]
lon=[int(l) for l in lon]
lat=[17., 17.5, 18., 18.5]
lat=[int(l) for l in lat]
time=[1, 3, 5, 7]
time=[int(l) for l in time]

fig=plt.figure()



for a1,b1 in zip(lon,lat):

    def init():
        fig
        return(fig),

    def animate(i):
        x,y=map(a1,b1)
        map.plot(x,y, linewidth = 1,color = 'm')
        return(map),

    anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(time), interval=1000)

    plt.show()
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I get the plot to move across the map? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code had quite a few problems. Maybe I just list them here and then you can ask questions if there is something you don't understand:

1. If no figure has been opened yet, the call to `Basemap` will generate a new figure. This makes the extra call to `plt.figure()` (kind of) redundant. I usually call `plt.figure` anyway, but *before* the call to `Basemap`.
2. When you use `FuncAnimation`, you do not have to loop through the values you want to animate -- `FuncAnimation` is doing this for you. The only thing that you need to provide is a function that updates the current plot according to the integer argument that `FuncAnimation` will provide to this function. In other words, the entire `for` loop you wrote is not the way to go.
3. Only call `plt.show()` once. Right now you call it every time you run through your `for` loop.
4. Don't call the `plot` command every time you want to update your plot. If everything else in your code would be correct, you would get many lines instead of just one. Instead update the data of the line object that is returned by `plot`. See the code below how this is done.
5. The amount of data points you provide and the amount of frames to want to animate do not match (4 vs 1000), which means that the animation will run "empty" for a long time.
6. Most of the coordinates you provide are outside of the map region that you display.
7. Don't call the Basemap object `map`, even though they do so in the tutorials. `map` is a reserved word in python. Rather use `m` or `bmap` or something.

Below I tried to correct the problems with your code, but it might be altered too much for your needs, so please ask if there is anything unclear:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig=plt.figure()

#map of Puerto Rico
bmap=Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=17.5,urcrnrlat=19.,llcrnrlon=-67.5, urcrnrlon=-65, epsg=4139)
bmap.arcgisimage(service='World_Shaded_Relief', xpixels = 2000)
plt.title("Flight Path of sbet 0059")

#sample coordinates
##lon=[-63,-64,-65,-66]
##lon=[int(l) for l in lon]
##lat=[17., 17.5, 18., 18.5]
##lat=[int(l) for l in lat]
##time=[1, 3, 5, 7]
##time=[int(l) for l in time]

#generate the flight coordinates (just a straight line with 100 points)
N = 100
lon = np.linspace(-64, -68, N)
lat = np.linspace(17, 19.5, N)

#only convert the coordinates once    
x,y = bmap(lon, lat)

#generate the original line object with only one point
line, = bmap.plot(x[0], y[0], linewidth = 1, color = 'm')

def animate(i):
    #this is doing all the magic. Every time animate is called, the line
    #will become longer by one point:
    line.set_data(x[:i],y[:i])  
    return line

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=N, interval=N)

plt.show()
```